# What does “%.#s” mean in printf?

Tags: c, printf

I have got a question in hackerearth to check if there is an error in this printf statement.Can you tell me if there is any meaning for this line below? Here

```
str="qwertyABC"

printf("%.#s",str)
```

Comment: See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: The posted code does not compile for several reasons, including that both statement are missing a trailing semicolon `';` and variable `str` is missing a type declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement will invoke *undefined behavior* because format specification is invalid since `#` is not defined as a conversion specifier.

To use `#` as a flag, it must be placed before `.`, which specifies the precision.

Moreover, using `#` as a flag, like `printf("%#.s",str)` will also invoke *undefined behavior* because the `#` ("alternative form") flag is not defined for the `%s` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** errors in your `printf` statement:

1. The `#` is ***not*** a valid field width or precision specifier.
2. The statement is missing a terminating semicolon.